# Nginx не связывает домен и localhost

Tags: nginx

.conf который отдается nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <myapp>.xyz;

    location / {
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:1400;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:1400

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>404</title>
</head>
<body style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
  <img alt="404" src="/api/utils-service/404" style="width: calc(50vw + 10vh);">
</body>
```

Если перейти по `http:<myapp>.xyz` то перекинет на `hello from nginx`

При чем я абсолютно не понимаю, что не так делаю и почему nginx не проксирует на myapp

Comment: nginx перезапускали после изменения конфига?

Comment: @VladimirIgnatenko Да. Так же вместо `127.0.0.1:1400` пробовал другие варианты типа `http://localhost:1400`, `0.0.0.0:1400` и т.д.

Comment: А кэш браузера почистить не забыли?

Comment: @andreymal ток сайчас попробовал с телефона зайти (1 раз), ничегт не работает, по прежнему `welcome to nginx` выдает

Comment: Тогда поехали по глупым вопросам — а этот конфиг nginx вообще применяется хоть? Где он находится и что вы предприняли для того, чтобы nginx его считывал?

Comment: @andreymal в главном конфиге nginx есть строчка`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` (она не закомментирована), конфиг сайта находится в `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/1400.conf`. Nginx его считывает как минимум из за того, что при переходе на домен сайта вместо "page is unavailable" показывает стандартную страничку nginx. Приложение на 0.0.0.0:1400 запросы от nginx не получает (логи пустые, хотя на curl отзывается)
`

Comment: nginx будет показывать стандартную страничку nginx даже без этого конфига. Поэтому предлагаю продолжить череду глупых вопросов - что если остановить nginx, стандартная страничка перестанет открываться? Если специально добавить синтаксическую ошибку в конфиг, чтобы nginx сломался - он сломается?

Comment: @andreymal так, теперь я вообще ничего не понимаю. Nginx, если добавить ошибку в конфиг сайта, не запустится => конфиг он видит. Но если конфиг удалить, то стандартная страничка таковой на сайте и останется + логи приложения на локалхосте пустые => nginx конфиг не применяет... 
`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` в главном конфиге присутствует там где надо...

Comment: Стандартная страничка обычно есть в конфиге default в том же sites-enabled. Но бездумно удалять его не надо - надо разобраться, почему nginx не хочет применять ваш конфиг (но у меня идеи пока что закончились)

Comment: @andreymal боже, я наткнулся на проблему!
`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` не принимает `1400.conf`, а значит эту строку надо заменить на `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;`... Я бы сейчас выразился, да неприлично

Comment: Ну вообще-то должен был принимать, что-то странное у вас

Comment: @andreymal да, должен был. В чем проблема, сам не знаю =(